# Listから取り出したボタンを　1秒まってからボタンの色を変えたい。

Tags: android, java

以下のコードで数字が格納されたリストからひとつずつ取り出して、反復処理をしています。ところがこのコードを実行するとボタンの色が同時にかわる現象が発生します。

デバッグを実行しステップイン実行するとたしかに反復処理になっているのですが、なぜこのようなことがおこるか全くわかりませんでした。

前回の質問ではThread.sleep()を使用して待機させていたのですが、for文の処理が全て終わってからボタンの色が変わりました。

**今までに試したこと**
①ハンドラー：ハンドラーを使うと色が同時に変わる
②timer.scedule(): sceduleも結果は一緒で同時に色が変わる
③Thread.sleep(): Thread.sleep()を使うとfor文が終了して色が変わる
④switch文全体をtimer処理しようと思いついたが、ローカル変数をうけとることができない。
⑤ローカルにアクセスするためにrun()メソッドにfor文を書けばよいと思ったが構文ルールに反するみたい

「色を変える→１秒止まる->また色を変える」とやりたいだけなのですが・・・

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
for(int r : randomList){
    switch (r) {
        case 1:
            button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }, 100);
            break;
        case 2:
            button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }, 100);
            break;
        case 3:
            button3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    button3.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }, 100);
            break;
        case 4:
            button4.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    button4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }, 100);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ステップ実行なんかを使わずに試して見るとわかるはずですが、`for(int r : randomList){...}`の処理は一瞬(せいぜいマイクロ秒のオーダー)で全部終了します。ほとんど同時に「100msec後にこれやってくれ」と言うことを登録している(`postDelayed(..., 100)`)のですから、そこから100msec後に全部の「これやって」がほとんど同時に走ることになります。「1秒間隔で何かの処理を繰り返し行いたい」と言うことであれば、`Timer`を使われた方が良いでしょう。そのうち詳しい回答を書ける方がこの質問を見つけられるでしょうが、それまでご自分で"Android Timer 使い方"あたりで調べて見てはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ちょっと理解しがたいのですが、同時になる理由がわかりません。100ミリ待機したあとに次に反復処理がはじまるのであればほぼ同時になる意味がわかりません。これはjava特有のものですか？

Timerを使った処理は調べてみます。

Comment: 「100ミリ待機したあとに次に反復処理がはじまるのであれば」と言う大前提が間違っています。あなたが「24時間後にこれをしといてくれ」と10人に頼んだとしても、あなたは10日間も待つことなく全員に頼み終わるでしょう。そしてそれから24時間後、頼まれた10人がほとんど同時に「これ」を実行することになります。`postDelayed(「これ」, 100)`は「100msec後にこれをしといてくれ」と頼んだだけであり、100ミリ待機することはありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。理解できました。

Comment: `for`文を想定した処理を`Timer`に変換するのは結構大変です。「同様の結果」になるのだとしたら、「`Timer`は使っているけど`postDelayed(「これ」, 100)`と同様の意味になることしかしていない」可能性が高いです。こちらAndroid開発環境はだいぶ前に捨ててしまったので、こうやれば確実に動きますよと言う回答が書けないのですが、試してみられたコードをご質問の後ろに追記されれば、今後あなたの質問を見られた方が回答を書きやすくなるかもしれません。

Comment: あと、`Timer`を使わずにこの質問の元のコードからの修正を最小限にする方法ですが、`postDelayed`にしている遅延時間を、ループの1回目なら`100`(1秒なら1000だとおもいますが、そこらへんは調整してください)、2回目なら`200`、3回目なら`300`…とだんだん増やしていっても同じ効果が得られると思います。ちなみに「③Thread.sleep()」については、Androidシステム側がUIスレッドで動かさないといけない処理がブロックされる(画面に変更が反映されないのもその一つ)ので、「UIスレッド内ではやってはいけない」と覚えておいた方が良いです。

Comment: おっしゃるとおりのやり方でなんとか解決できました。挫折しそうでした。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

**コメントでの助言もあり解決しました（質問者自身による投稿）**

```
 for (int r : randomList) {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){

                        }
                    }, listCount3);

                    switch (r) {
                        case 1:
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                                public void run(){
                                    button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                }
                            }, listCount);
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                                public void run(){
                                    button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                                }
                            }, listCount2);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                                public void run(){
                                    button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                }
                            }, listCount);
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                                }
                            }, listCount2);
                            break;

                    }
                    listCount += 500; listCount2 += 500; listCount3 += 500;
                }
```

①postDelayed()メソッドの待機時間に使うためのフィールドを３つ宣言する
②postDelayed()メソッドの待機時間を全部ずらすことで順番にボタンの色が変わるのを再現。

**解決はしましたが他の方法があれば教えてほしいです**
C#ではawaitを使用することで簡単に再現できました。javaでawaitに該当するようなものがあればと思うのですが・・・。Thread.Sleep()のように簡単に使えてうまくいくようなメソッドなりがあればと思いました。

Answer (score 0):

await ではありませんが、スレッドを作って `Thread.sleep()` する方法はいかがでしょう。

```
    private void stepTest() {
        final int[] randomList = new int[] { 1, 3, 2, 4 };
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        final Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final Button button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (int r: randomList) {
                        switch (r) {
                        case 1:
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                }
                            });
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                                }
                            });
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                }
                            });
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                                }
                            });
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    button3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                }
                            });
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    button3.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                                }
                            });
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    button4.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                }
                            });
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    button4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    android.util.Log.e("StepTest", "interrupted", e);
                }
            }
        };

        Thread thr = new Thread(runnable);
        thr.start();
    }
```

ただし、このサンプルには以下の処理がないですが。

- 処理が終わった頃に、どこかで `thr.join()` する
- 中断したくなったら、`thr.interrupt()` する